# Plot stacked chart with javascript with negatives values

Tags: javascript, charts, stacked

I need to plot this with javascript (excel chart): http://pontt.com/plotexcel.jpg (bar below the x-axis and bar above the x-axis).

Anyone know of a javascript library (except google charts) that supports stacked bar charts with negative values and the plot just as excel?

I tried several libraries, but I had no success in trying to plot with negative values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried it, but have a look at [flotr](http://code.google.com/p/flotr/). I think it supports such a thing. Hope it helps.